# null response usin Retrofit Library in android

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit2

Here is my `JSONArray` Response from Web service:

[image: Show Image]

And Class Java :

```
public class Product {

  private int id,price,discount;
  private String name,image,description,discount_type,discount_exp;

  @SerializedName("products")
  private List<Product> products;

  public Product()
  {

  }

}
```

response is null

Comment: First of all, that's not an Array response. Sounds like you're parsing it wrong. Please show your Retrofit code

Comment: And a Product itself does not contain a list of Products

Comment: You can create your model from this site http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: See my updated post it will help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `POJO` `class` is wrong

Try this

```
public class Products_Main
{
  @SerializedName("current_page")
  int current_page;

  @SerializedName("data")
  private List<Product> products;

  public int getCurrent_page() {
    return current_page;
  }

  public void setCurrent_page(int current_page) {
    this.current_page = current_page;
  }

  public List<Product> getProducts() {
    return products;
  }

  public void setProducts(List<Product> products) {
    this.products = products;
  }
}
```

and

```
class Product {

    @SerializedName("id")
    private int id;

    @SerializedName("price")
    int price;

    @SerializedName("discount")
    int discount;

    @SerializedName("name")
    private String name;

    @SerializedName("image")
    private String image;

    @SerializedName("description")
    private String description;

    @SerializedName("discount_type")
    private String discount_type;

    @SerializedName("discount_exp")
    private String discount_exp;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getDiscount() {
        return discount;
    }

    public void setDiscount(int discount) {
        this.discount = discount;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getDiscount_type() {
        return discount_type;
    }

    public void setDiscount_type(String discount_type) {
        this.discount_type = discount_type;
    }

    public String getDiscount_exp() {
        return discount_exp;
    }

    public void setDiscount_exp(String discount_exp) {
        this.discount_exp = discount_exp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the products are contained within the data field of the `JSON` response. `Retrofit` doesn't know this so it can't deserialize the response into a Product array.

Comment: how access to products > data ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change like it will work

```
public class ProductModel {

    private int current_page;

    private ArrayList<DataModel> data = new ArrayList<>();

    public int getCurrent_page() {
        return current_page;
    }

    public void setCurrent_page(int current_page) {
        this.current_page = current_page;
    }

    public ArrayList<DataModel> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(ArrayList<DataModel> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    private class DataModel{

        private int id,price,discount,shop_id,vote_id,vedeo_id,status;
        private String name,image,description,discount_type,discount_exp,created_at,updated_at;

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public int getPrice() {
            return price;
        }

        public void setPrice(int price) {
            this.price = price;
        }

        public int getDiscount() {
            return discount;
        }

        public void setDiscount(int discount) {
            this.discount = discount;
        }

        public int getShop_id() {
            return shop_id;
        }

        public void setShop_id(int shop_id) {
            this.shop_id = shop_id;
        }

        public int getVote_id() {
            return vote_id;
        }

        public void setVote_id(int vote_id) {
            this.vote_id = vote_id;
        }

        public int getVedeo_id() {
            return vedeo_id;
        }

        public void setVedeo_id(int vedeo_id) {
            this.vedeo_id = vedeo_id;
        }

        public int getStatus() {
            return status;
        }

        public void setStatus(int status) {
            this.status = status;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getImage() {
            return image;
        }

        public void setImage(String image) {
            this.image = image;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }

        public void setDescription(String description) {
            this.description = description;
        }

        public String getDiscount_type() {
            return discount_type;
        }

        public void setDiscount_type(String discount_type) {
            this.discount_type = discount_type;
        }

        public String getDiscount_exp() {
            return discount_exp;
        }

        public void setDiscount_exp(String discount_exp) {
            this.discount_exp = discount_exp;
        }

        public String getCreated_at() {
            return created_at;
        }

        public void setCreated_at(String created_at) {
            this.created_at = created_at;
        }

        public String getUpdated_at() {
            return updated_at;
        }

        public void setUpdated_at(String updated_at) {
            this.updated_at = updated_at;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how access to products > data ?

Answer (score 0):

Any null data happens when the parsing failed.

This is the Java for the response you've shown

```
public class ProductResponse {
    ProductPage products;
} 

public class ProductPage {
    int current_page;

    @SerializedName("data")
    private List<Product> products;
} 

public class Product {
  private int id,price,discount;
  private String name,image,description,discount_type,discount_exp;

  public Product() { }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use it like that

=>Main API Model Class

```
 public class APIResult {
        @SerializedName("products")
        private ProductModelClass products;

        public ProductModelClass getProducts() {
            return products;
        }

        public void setProducts(ProductModelClass products) {
            this.products = products;
        }
    }
```

=>For data and current page  model class

```
public class ProductModelClass {

    @SerializedName("current_page")
    private int current_page;

    @SerializedName("data")
    private ArrayList<ProductDataModel> data;

    public int getCurrent_page() {
        return current_page;
    }

    public void setCurrent_page(int current_page) {
        this.current_page = current_page;
    }

    public ArrayList<ProductDataModel> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(ArrayList<ProductDataModel> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

=>For Details of products Data

```
public class ProductDataModel {

    @SerializedName("id")
    private int id;

    @SerializedName("name")
    private String name;

    @SerializedName("image")
    private String image;

    @SerializedName("description")
    private String description;

    @SerializedName("price")
    private int price;

    @SerializedName("discount")
    private int discount;

    @SerializedName("shop_id")
    private int shop_id;

    @SerializedName("discount_type")
    private String discount_type;

    @SerializedName("discount_exp")
    private String discount_exp;

    @SerializedName("discount_limit")
    private String discount_limit;

    @SerializedName("vote_id")
    private String vote_id;

    @SerializedName("video_id")
    private String video_id;

    @SerializedName("status")
    private String status;

    @SerializedName("created_at")
    private String created_at;

    @SerializedName("updated_at")
    private String updated_at;


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getDiscount() {
        return discount;
    }

    public void setDiscount(int discount) {
        this.discount = discount;
    }

    public int getShop_id() {
        return shop_id;
    }

    public void setShop_id(int shop_id) {
        this.shop_id = shop_id;
    }

    public String getDiscount_type() {
        return discount_type;
    }

    public void setDiscount_type(String discount_type) {
        this.discount_type = discount_type;
    }

    public String getDiscount_exp() {
        return discount_exp;
    }

    public void setDiscount_exp(String discount_exp) {
        this.discount_exp = discount_exp;
    }

    public String getDiscount_limit() {
        return discount_limit;
    }

    public void setDiscount_limit(String discount_limit) {
        this.discount_limit = discount_limit;
    }

    public String getVote_id() {
        return vote_id;
    }

    public void setVote_id(String vote_id) {
        this.vote_id = vote_id;
    }

    public String getVideo_id() {
        return video_id;
    }

    public void setVideo_id(String video_id) {
        this.video_id = video_id;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getCreated_at() {
        return created_at;
    }

    public void setCreated_at(String created_at) {
        this.created_at = created_at;
    }

    public String getUpdated_at() {
        return updated_at;
    }

    public void setUpdated_at(String updated_at) {
        this.updated_at = updated_at;
    }
}
```